# Min, Max, Infimum, and Supremum

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to answer the following question but I’m not sure if I’m on the right track… please give me any feedback!!

Find the min, max, infimum, and supremum for each of the following.

```
{1,3}       1, 3, 1, 3 

{π,3}       pi, 3, pi, 3

[0,4]       0, 4, 0, 4

(0,4)       none, none, 0, 4

{1/2n : n ∈N}      none, 1/2, 0, 1/2

{1-(1/n) : n ∈N}      0, none, 0, 1

{n/(n+1) : n ∈N}      0, none, 0, 1

{(-1)^n (1+(1/n)) : n ∈N}     0, none, 0, 1

{n+((-1)^n/n) : n ∈N}   0, none, 0, none

 (-∞,4)       none, none, negative infinity, 4

intersection of all elements from n=1 to ∞:[1-(1/n),1+(1/n)]    ???

union of all elements from n=1 to ∞ [1/n,2-(1/n)]   ???

{r ∈ rationals: r < 5}       none, none, 0 ,5

{r ∈ rationals: r^2≤5}     none, none, -sqrt 5, sqrt 5
```

Comment: Why do you think that $\pi \le 3$?

Comment: AFAIS $\mathbb{N}$ is set of positive intergers, so $\inf\{n/(n+1) : n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \min\{n/(n+1) : n \in \mathbb{N}\} = \frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $1 + \epsilon \notin [1 - \frac1n, 1 + \frac1n]$ and $1 - \epsilon \notin [1 - \frac1n, 1 + \frac1n]$ for all $n \ge N_{\epsilon}$. So
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty}[1 - \frac1n, 1 + \frac1n] = \{1\}.$$
The same idea for union. For any $1 \le \epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_{\epsilon}$ such that $\epsilon \in [\frac1n, 2 - \frac1n]$ and $2 - \epsilon \in [\frac1n, 2 - \frac1n]$ for all $n \ge N_{\epsilon}$. So
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}[\frac1n, 2 - \frac1n] = (0, 2).$$